# How to add XSD datatype restrictions to a DTD?

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I am trying to make a DTD in which I want to add some restrictions like:

- Only allow the introduction of telephone numbers with 9 numbers
- Only allow the introduction of an ID with 7 numbers and 1 letter

But I don't know how I can do that. (I know it is easier to add these restrictions with a XML Schema, but I want to do it with a DTD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***DTDs cannot restrict data to numeric types***, let alone limit the number of digits:

- **Elements**: DTDs define the [***content spec***](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-contentspec) of an element as

  > ```
  > [46]     contentspec ::=     'EMPTY' | 'ANY' | Mixed | children
  > ```

  Through `Mixed` we can declare #PCDATA (parsed character data) but
  make no further datatype specifications.  Through `children` we can
  declare child elements, recursively.

  **None of the element type possibilities afford the specification a numeric type or length.**
- **Attributes**: DTDs define an ***[attribute type](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttType)*** as a string, a set of tokenized types, or an enumerated type:

  > ```
  > [54]       AttType     ::=     StringType | TokenizedType | EnumeratedType
  > ```

  `TokenizedType` can be one of `ID`, `IDREF`, `IDREFS`, `ENTITY`, `ENTITIES`, `NMTOKEN`, or `NMTOKENS`; `EnumeratedType` can be an notation or an enumeration.

  **None of the attribute type possibilities afford the specification a numeric type or length.**

***Overall, there is no support for numeric types for elements or attributes.<sup>1</sup>*** Use XSD instead.

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>If you're in the extraordinary situation of needing to extend DTD to express broader datatypes such as those found in XSD, see [Datatypes for DTDs (DT4DTD) 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/dt4dtd).  However, do not expect existing validating parsers to enforce such specifications, which are more for *providing the foundation for a smoother future transition path* to XML Schema.</sub></sup>