# How to create a DTD Element that can ONLY contain text

Tags: xml, dtd

I am currently working on an external DTD file and am trying to create a DTD element that can only contain text, no numbers.

Currently I have my element as:

```
<!Element name(#PCDATA)>
```

But I think this means that it can accept all text (numbers, etc.) which is not what I am wanting.

Help? Thank you.

Comment: So the element can contain `A`, `b`, `ç`, `$`, `+`, `ë`, and `→` but not `0`?

Comment: You don't need to embed images. You just need to read the code formatting instructions next to the edit window (and not wipe out the edits I made to fix the problem for you).

Comment: Well, it should only contain letters (a, b, c, etc.). No symbols or character entities.

Comment: So `&#65;` is off the table but `A` is allowed even though they are identically equivilent in XML?

Comment: It is not possible to *create a DTD element that can only contain text, no numbers*. See [duplicate link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957102/how-to-add-xsd-datatype-restrictions-to-a-dtd) for further details.  (You have to use XSD if you want that level of control over element content type.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!